# Simply connected and connected in complex analysis

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

[image: simply connected]

Can some one please help me with this, why is third set in the picture not simply connected. The definition of simply connected (in space of complex numbers) is:

A set is said to be simply connected if every closed path in the set
is homotopic to a point.

so does this definition mean it must be homotopic to all points in our set or must there exist a point. 
Cause if it says there must exist a point then the third set must be simply connected right?

Comment: There ought to be a "... the set is connected and ..." (or something equivalent) in there. It may be that the book's author(s) forgot it, that's an erratum then, or you may have missed it. Check again carefully to see which is the case.

Comment: All it say is that the set must be a open set of complex.

Comment: i see why the 4th set is not simply connected, but why isnt the third one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *path-connected* topological space $X$ is simply connected if for any given point $x_0$ on $X$, any loop $\sigma$ based at $x_0$ is path-homotopic to the constant loop $e_{x_0}$ at $x_0$.

The third space (subset of $\Bbb C$) is not connected, so there is no path between a point in the first component and a point in the other, say. Thus this space is not path connected, hence simple connctedness is not defined.

Comment: can you not talk about simply connected on a general open set of the complex plane?

Comment: @george It works similarly. Replace $X$ by subsets of $\Bbb C$ with subspace topology.

Comment: More to the point, to define simple connectedness, you must have path-connectedness, but the third set is not even connected.

Comment: Thanks, with this definition it makes sense why set number 3 is not simply connected.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to describe the third picture would be to say it has *simply connected (path-)components*. In a sense it's almost as good as simple-connectedness since the common things you would need simply-connected open sets for (integrals of holomorphic functions around closed curves equal to 0, an antiderivative for every holomorphic function, etc.) work just as well by considering the components separately. But as a whole it is not simply connected because it has more than one connected component.